# What exactly does the vmware_guest attribute is_template do? -How to use it

Tags: windows, ansible-template

I'm trying to use Ansible's `vmware_guest` module to set a well configured Windows VM as a template via the `is_template` attribute with the hopes of preserving all configurations of the administrator profile when other VMs are templated from this well configured VM.  Am i dreaming?  Are there hopes of preserving any of such configuration(?); maybe preserve some service settings ...  -I know it's Windows nature to default/overwrite this profile during such operations but other configuration settings are getting reset too (so i'm hopeful).  However, i can't get to first base with this.  I've tried numerous task/play configurations to use this attribute so i can test the results but each attempt fails; **e.g.** `not supported on the object`.  -How can i establish such a template vm or (*better yet*) is this worth my effort given my goal?  I'm fearing that the only quality of this attribute is only to catalog the VM as a template (template library member) ...